# Previous record in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

In my table i have date records like 02-04-2016 , 03-01-2016 and 04-01-2016 if i am on 03-01-2016 i want the previous record which is 02-01-2016 But it gives me 01-01-2016 which is the first record of my table. No matter what date i am on.

```
if(isset($_POST['place'])){
$place      = $_POST['place'];
$date       = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
$classtype  = $_POST['classtype'];
$getdate    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `class` WHERE `city`='$place' AND `clastype`='$classtype' AND `classdate`<'$date' limit 0,1")or die(mysql_error());
$mydt       = mysql_fetch_array($getdate);

$mdt = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($mydt[classdate]));
echo $mdt;
}
```

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM `class` WHERE `city`='$place' AND `clastype`='$classtype' AND `classdate`<'$date' order by classdate desc limit 0,1`

Comment: nope not working @AmitSarwara still jumping on the first

Comment: For an easy life, why not store dates using a date data type? And note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: He must be using a date type field for class date. aren't you?, because date field will help you get record better.

Comment: yes i am using date type field for classdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM `class` WHERE `city`='$place' AND `clastype`='$classtype' AND `classdate`<'$date' order by `classdate` desc limit 0,1"
```

Please use order by clause.

Comment: Better to order by date, ins't it?

Comment: order by classdate because your date field is classdate.

Comment: Yaah it worked thanks Shailesh Katarmal and thanks everyone else

Comment: "SELECT * FROM `class` WHERE `city`='$place' AND `clastype`='$classtype' AND `classdate`<'$date' order by `classdate` desc limit 0,1"

Answer (score 0):

Use ORDER BY clause

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `class` 
WHERE `city`='$place' AND `clastype`='$classtype' AND 
      `classdate`<'$date' 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```